# How to expose simple console host web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I need to write simple web service that will not be hosted by iis => so i using simple console application to be the host.

I created 2 project

1) dll that contain the IService.cd & Service.cs
2) console application that will the the host.

and all the rest of my steps are same as [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/225740/self-hosting-of-wcf-service-with-console-application/)

But when i run my application -- i can't see the service from other machine like i can when i define the host to be the IIS.

How to solve it ?

the config file:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True"/>
    <services>
      <service name="CalcService.Calc" behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9003/Calc"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002/Calc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9003/Calc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CalcService.ICalc"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9002/Calc" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="CalcService.ICalc"/>-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost svcHost = null;
        try
        {
            svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalcService.Calc));
            svcHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nService is Running  at following address");

            Console.WriteLine("\nhttp://localhost:9001/Calc");
            Console.WriteLine("\nnet.tcp://localhost:9002/Calc");
        }
        catch(Exception eX)
        {
            svcHost = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Service can not be started \n\nError Message [" + eX.Message + "]");
        }

        if(svcHost != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to close the Service");
            Console.ReadKey();
            svcHost.Close();
            svcHost = null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Show the code on how you host your service.

Comment: add the host service - embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you need to transfer all configuration in your app.config where your console application is situated.

You could considered below links to check if your service is working properly.

- [How to host wcf server on application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031630/how-to-host-wcf-server-on-application/32064927#32064927)
- [WCF- console hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958241/wcf-console-hosting/31978251#31978251)
- [Host Multiple Wcf Services On Local IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515594/host-multiple-wcf-services-on-local-iis-6/31542823#31542823)

And for addition multiple endpoints you can follow this link from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).